# How many unit test should be run after building a node?

Tags: nodes, ecash, make

After building Bitcoin ABC and running `make check`, I get this:

```
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

There is one unit test binary which contains several hundred tests within it. `make check` just runs the binary, and if none of the tests within it fail, then `make check` passes. Because there is only one binary, `make check` sees this as being only one unit test, but in reality, all 200+ tests are just packaged into the same binary.